# jquery function not working properly in safari

Tags: html, jquery

I am working on the following code. This function creates a "typed" effect. This function works well in chrome but not in safari. Is there an issue with jquery for safari?

```
var Typed = (function() {

    var typed = '.typed',
        $typed = $(typed);


    function init($this) {
        var el = '#' + $this.attr('id'),
            strings = $this.data('type-this'),
            strings = strings.split(',');

        var options = {
            strings: strings,
            typeSpeed: 100,
            backSpeed: 70,
            loop: true
        };

        var animation = new Typed(el, options);

        inView(el).on('enter', function() {
            animation.start();
        }).on('exit', function() {
            animation.stop();
        });
    }

    if ($typed.length) {
        $typed.each(function() {
            init($(this));
        });
    }

})();
```

```
<span class="typed" id="type-example-1" data-type-this="text1., text2., text3., text4."></span>
```

Comment: Where does `inView()` come from? Any errors in safari?

Comment: Why doesn't it work in Safari?

Comment: Try another version of Jquery